# XCode 4 on snow leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, xcode

Is it still possible to get XCode 4 on snow leopard? I downgraded earlier today from lion, and need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will work unless you have a paid account which you can download old versions.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/no-more-xcode-4-for-snow-leopard

Comment: Paid account for iOS dev or mac dev? I have a paid iOS dev account, is that good enough?

Comment: Yes that'll be fine, you'll have access to all versions

Comment: Hmm, because I can access xcode 3 with ios4.3 sdk just fine, but if I click the link titled "Xcode 4.1 for Snow Leopard" is says The download you requested is not available for download. Registered Apple Developers and ADC members may view the downloads that are currently available.
If i click view the downloads, xcode 4 for snow leopard isn't anywhere in there.